# Calling angular-datatable ajax call on other api response

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatable ( http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way) .

Instead on assigning to this.dtOptions in ngOnInit, I want to do it in the response of another api, but the ajax call is not going through.

My code :-

```
ngOnInit(){
this.firstCall();
}

firstCall(){
  this.api.serviceMethod().subscribe((data : model1) => {
   this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: data.pageLength,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'api.com/api',
            dataTablesParameters, data.req_body, {}
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.persons = resp.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: []
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
    };
})
}
```

When I am putting the dtOptions assignment in ngOnInit, it is getting called, what am I missing here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest use another library for tables that **not** use jQuery, really I want to recognize the effort to make and maintain a library, but has no sense (never had it) use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You must set a check in super tag (like : tbody or table when you loop in tr tag).

 component.html

```
<table *ngIf="!loading" ...>
  ...
```

...

component.ts

```
  loading = true;
... .subscribe(resp => {
        that.persons = resp.data;
        loading = false;
```